# Insert a column at the beginning (leftmost end) of a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, insert

I have dataframe with 30 columns and want to add one new column to start.

Comment: duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18674064/how-do-i-insert-a-column-at-a-specific-column-index-in-pandas

Answer (score 29, accepted):

**[`DataFrame.insert`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.insert.html)**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['x'] * 3, 'B': ['x'] * 3})
df

   A  B
0  x  x
1  x  x
2  x  x

seq = ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

```
# This works in-place.
df.insert(0, 'C', seq)
df

   C  A  B
0  a  x  x
1  b  x  x
2  c  x  x
```

---

**[`pd.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.concat.html#pandas-concat)**

```
df = pd.concat([pd.Series(seq, index=df.index, name='C'), df], axis=1)
df

   C  A  B
0  a  x  x
1  b  x  x
2  c  x  x
```

---

**[`DataFrame.reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) + [`assign`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html)**
Reindex first, then assign will remember the position of the original column.

```
df.reindex(['C', *df.columns], axis=1).assign(C=seq)

   C  A  B
0  a  x  x
1  b  x  x
2  c  x  x
```

Comment: How can we insert it to the end (last column)? Why doesn't `df.insert(-1, 'C', seq)` work?

Comment: To insert columns in the end just do `df['C'] = seq`.