# Cannot add total column into existing Indexed DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm a newbie in Python, and currently trying to repeat examples from the books and courses. And in all cases I'm quite a lot struggling with DataFrame structure, it seems like it has been hugely changed from 2.7 to 3.0

Basically, in the current example, I want to add a total column (total for each year). so I've done the following

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn
flights = seaborn.load_dataset('flights')
flights_indexed = flights.set_index(['year','month'])
flights_unstacked = flights_indexed.unstack();
```

[image]

from the example, the following line should work, but it doesn't in python3

```
flights_unstacked['passengers','total'] = flights_unstacked.sum(axis=1)
```

I found a few links that show how to add the column ([link1](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.insert.html), [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18674064/how-do-i-insert-a-column-at-a-specific-column-index-in-pandas)), but none of this work for me

```
flights_unstacked["passengers"].insert(loc=0,column="total", value=flights_unstacked.sum(axis=1).values)
```

In both cases, the error is the same `cannot insert an item into a CategoricalIndex that is not already an existing category`

I have a feeling that it must be something more tricky as my DataFrame no more completely flat, it's currently grouped and I want to add the total values precisely on the "month" level.

I would be super happy even if someone let me know how to google it!

Comment: Try: `flights_unstacked['passengers']['total'] = flights_unstacked.sum(axis=1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the column 'month' in the flight data is of type `category`. So when it's unstacked it, it creates a [`pd.CategoricalIndex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.CategoricalIndex.html) and 'total' is not one of the valid categories.

### Solution 1

The quickest and easiest fix would be to cast that column as type `object`:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn
flights = seaborn.load_dataset('flights')

# Casting here
flights['month'] =  flights.month.astype('O')

# Should work as intended now
flights_indexed = flights.set_index(['year','month'])
flights_unstacked = flights_indexed.unstack()
flights_unstacked['passengers','total'] = flights_unstacked.sum(axis=1)
```

[Here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/categorical.html) is some more information on `categorical` data.

---

### Solution 2

How you could handle this whilst maintaining `categorical` datatype.

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn
flights = seaborn.load_dataset('flights')

flights.month.dtype
```

This shows the categories of this field as...

```
CategoricalDtype(categories=['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June',
                  'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November',
                  'December'],
                 ordered=False)
```

So you can see in this case 12 categories, the months 'January' .. 'December'.

You can add additional categories using:

```
flights.month.cat.add_categories('total', inplace=True)
```

And checking the categories again...

```
flights.month.dtype

CategoricalDtype(categories=['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June',
                  'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November',
                  'December', 'total'],
                 ordered=False)
```

'total' was added as a valid category.

The following should now work:

```
flights_indexed = flights.set_index(['year','month'])
flights_unstacked = flights_indexed.unstack()
flights_unstacked['passengers','total'] = flights_unstacked.sum(axis=1)
```

Comment: thanks for the quick answer! Could you please explain a bit what's the trick with conversion to an object?

Comment: @VladimirSemashkin Not a trick really, just removing all of the behaviour and nuances of `categorical` type by converting it to a string. I've added an alternative solution that maintains the categorical type to show how it works