# Pandas Sum on the first column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I know this question is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18674064/how-do-i-insert-a-column-at-a-specific-column-index-in-pandas) but my question is to have the sum of all values as I am fairly new to pandas and I don't have any Idea to pull this off.

currently, I can sum all the value of columns and add it on the df with the 
following code

`df.loc[:,'x':'y'].sum(axis = 1)`

```
+---+---+---+-------+
| x | y | z | total |
+---+---+---+-------+
| 1 | 2 | 1 |     4 |
| 0 | 1 | 1 |     2 |
| 1 | 0 | 0 |     1 |
+---+---+---+-------+
```

is there a way to have the sum of all columns and place it on the start of the dataframe?

```
+-------+---+---+---+
| total | x | y | z |
+-------+---+---+---+
|     4 | 1 | 2 | 1 |
|     2 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
|     1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
+-------+---+---+---+
```

Comment: `df.insert(0,'total',df.loc[:,'x':'y'].sum(axis = 1))`

Comment: thank you, please answer so I can mark it.

Comment: You are welcome. Unfortunately it is a dupe, so i will let it be. :)

Comment: well it is different from just inserting at any place. Or I'm just fairly new to Pandas and I don't know what I'm doing. But thank you very much for the answer.