# How to add text element to series data in Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a series data in python defined as:

```
scores_data = (pd.Series([F1[0], auc, ACC[0], FPR[0], FNR[0], TPR[0], TNR[0]])).round(4)
```

I want to append the text 'Featues' at location 0 to the series data.

I tried `scores_data.loc[0]` but that replaced the data at location 0.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how do I insert a column at a specific column index in pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18674064/how-do-i-insert-a-column-at-a-specific-column-index-in-pandas)

Comment: @C0rn this only works for DataFrames

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't directly insert a value in a Series (like you could in a DataFrame with [`insert`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.insert.html)).

You can use [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html#pandas.concat):

```
s = pd.Series([1,2,3,4])

s2 = pd.concat([pd.Series([0], index=[-1]), s])
```

output:

```
-1    0
 0    1
 1    2
 2    3
 3    4
dtype: int64
```

Or create a new Series from the values:

```
pd.Series([0]+s.to_list())
```

output:

```
0    0
1    1
2    2
3    3
4    4
dtype: int64
```

Comment: thanks for your input.  I tried to input the text column, but I am still stuck.  I converted the text data to a series, but still have issues inserting the text.  Using your example, this was my attempt:  `s = pd.Series([1,2,3,4])
s2 = pd.Series(['FeatExtr'])

pd.Series(s[0]+s2.to_list())`